# Laravel Authorization: Redirect instead of exception?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to give users that are logged in and are of a specific type (`leader`) access to all pages handled by a controller. In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication) I found that I can use `$this->middleware('Auth')` inside a constructor, which will redirect all users that are not logged in yet. However I didnt find how to do this when instead of checking if the user is logged in one rather checks if the user is allowed by a [gate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates).

In `AuthServiceProvider` I created the following Gate

```
Gate::define('isLeader', function ($user) {
  return $user->isLeader();
});
```

Inside a controller I have the following constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('can:isLeader');
}
```

For users who are a `leader` this works. But for users who are not a `leader` I get the error message `This action is unauthorized.` when accessing a page through this controller:

[image]

Instead of throwing an error message I would rather redirect the user to `home` if he is not a `leader`. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Just re-posting the [answer given in laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/policy-authorize-redirect-instead-of-403?page=0).

You can do this in the Exceptions\Handler.php file

The render method overrides the classes AuthorizationException which is what authorize() will throw if a user is denied.

Inside the render method you could do

```
if($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
//your code
}
```